# How to represent a type table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, enums

i have two tables **agency**, and **agency_type**
agency has reference to **agency_type_id**
the table **agency_type** has two value= **individual**, **corporate**
i see that some examples represents the type table with an **Enum**, is that is the best practice in such case ? and does this creates a database table for the enum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it can be just a column in table agency of type int(11) and the description will be like this:

```
    <class name="com....Agency" table="agency">
        ............
        <property name="agencyType" column="agency_type_id">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">com...AgencyType</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        .............
    </class>
```

Comment: If there is fixed or rarely changed number of values (like individual, corporate) then Enum is the most appropriate Java type for that. Basically, it's not even part of data - it's part of code. Hibernate provides an easy way to map enums. It's much simpler than using a separate table with a couple of values.

Comment: thanks for your help, can you please provide sample code with annotations, rather than xml